# Is there a "sustainable" way to add something to the dashboard?

Tags: bolt-cms

It looks like it's easy to add stuff to dashboard.twig, but what is the best practice, keeping future Bolt updates in mind?

1 line of code referring to an include? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

For Bolt 1.6, take a look at the Google Analytics extension, since it adds a dashboard widget.

With 2.0 the way this works might slightly change, though. We'll need to figure out it we want extensions to be able to add widgets to any page.